How do I make a graph to model the trend of retail sales, and also extrapolate/predict the trend for future years?
This is the data sheet I want to use - https://www.ons.gov.uk/businessindustryandtrade/retailindustry/datasets/retailsalesindexreferencetables. Can someone tell me what I can use to put the data (firstly just from one of the columns) from the first sheet called CPSA into a graph with date on the x-axis and sales on y-axis, like matplotlib in python, or another library/application?
I've tried using matplotlib to create a graph as a nice way to represent this data, but it didn't work as the sheet is too complex, so could someone tell me how to at least set it up? Also, would there be a way to model all the variables or would just one variable be more effective?

"The sheet is too complex" - if you can't figure out which values to pull from the sheet, there's probably nobody here who can help you.  That doesn't sound like a programming problem.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are asking a question which put simply amounts to please solve the problem of global economic forecasting. Even governments struggle with it. Giving a link to a 10MB compressed XL file is nothing like an Minimal Reproducible Example. There are companies that will do this sort of stuff for you for a price (think $$$$$) their results are almost as unreliable as the treasury's. You should be able to plot things in Excel if you can decide what it is you want to do.

PS on the day of what may be a landslide election result in the UK completely changing the entire political landscape you should also be aware of the old adage that "past performance is no guide to the future ".

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
